# Generically bind scriptblock parameters from array passed to ArgumentList

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I'm looking to make it possible to bind the values of an object array to the parameters of a scriptblock in a generic way where I don't know in advance the parameters defined by the scriptblock. For example:

```cs
function test {
    Param([object[]] $allargs)
    Write-Host "allargs: $allargs"

    $sb = {
        param($firstname, $age, $lastname)

        Write-Host "Hello `"$firstname`". Your age is: '$age' and your last name is $lastname"
    }

    & $sb $allargs
}

cls
test "Bob","20","Smith"
```

Outputs:

```
allargs: Bob 20 Smith
Hello "Bob 20 Smith". Your age is: '' and your last name is
```

Comment: As a follow up, how could the following be made to work? `test @{firstname="Bob";age="20";lastname="Smith"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) as in:

    `& $sb @allargs`

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me insane. I always forget about splatting. Hopefully this has beaten it into my head.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$args`, [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) it on the scriptblock, and invoke your function with 3 distinct arguments, not one array argument:

```
function test {
    Write-Host "allargs: $args"

    $sb = {
        Param($firstname, $age, $lastname)

        Write-Host "Hello '${firstname}'. Your age is: '${age}' and your last name is '${lastname}'"
    }

    & $sb @args
}

test  'Bob' '20' 'Smith'
```